# Cant make UIlabel text blink in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to make my **UILabel** blink in Xcode
but the problem is it does not blink

Here is my code:

```
 self.labelCountdownTime.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];
self.labelCountdownTime.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: This works fine for me, check if you have connected the outlet properly. But a better approach would be use a `UIView` animation block.

Comment: its defiantly connected. I'm new to this, what do you mean by using UIView block?

Comment: see answer by khuong291, its the 3rd code i am refering to.

Comment: i tried it but my label does not blink. do you think i am implementing the code wrong

Comment: You just copy my code, but you don't see the labels name are different -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` to blink your text in UILabel like so:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer 
                      scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(1.0)
                            target:self 
                             selector:@selector(blink) 
                             userInfo:nil 
                             repeats:YES];
BOOL blinkStatus = NO;
```

And the selector will call this function:

```
-(void)blink{
   if(blinkStatus == NO){
      yourLabel.alpha = 1.0;
     blinkStatus = YES;
   }else {
      yourLabel.alpha = 0.0;
      blinkStatus = NO;
   }
}
```

Or you can use method `animationWithDuration` of `UIView` like so:

```
self.yourLabel.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 1;
} completion:nil];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i just tried both of your methods, the first one comes up with a couple of errors and the second one does not blink. Am i implementing the code wrong?

Comment: change your label name in there!

Comment: there is no error, the app build is successful but the uilabel does not blink. its like the app just ignores the code

Comment: how would i do that? sorry I'm new to this

Comment: just 1 click on the left on the line

Comment: Is it ok? Did you debug success?

Comment: hi, I'm not exactly sure by what you mean with 1 click on the left on the line.

Comment: Can we go on chat room?

Comment: Or can we talk in skype :)

Comment: can i email you at your gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are wanting some thing more like the following:
Create a timer in your controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

then start the timer where you need it to start, like maybe in **viewDidLoad**

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(toggleLabelAlpha) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and here is the selector:

```
- (void)toggleLabelAlpha {

[self.labelCountdownTime setHidden:(!self.labelCountdownTime.hidden)];
}
```

Try this ?

Comment: the app just crashes when i use this :(

Comment: Sorry I was unable to help.  This works for me in a old project I had.  I did make an edit at the same time as you commented, because i had self.label.hidden instead of self.labelCountdowntime.hidden which, if you copied directly without edited, would have caused some problems